# How wide do two doors at 90 degree angles have to be to allow a specific piano to slide in?

Tags: area, angle

I'd be super grateful for some help with this practical question relating to angles and area.

I'm a musician (not a mathematician, sadly) and I'm building a recording studio in my garden. I'm trying to figure out how to get the most out of my space, but need to allow enough room to slide an upright piano in - presumably at a diagonal angle through the entrance and the side door to the left. Please see below pics for studio dimensions and the door layout, and dimensions of the piano.

My questions is, how wide do the entrance door (opening forwards, not shown here) and left door (opening backwards) have to be to allow the piano to safely slide in? I can't think for the life of me how I'm supposed to work this out. Of course I could play it safe and make the entrance doors >153cm wide and then move it orthogonally to the left, but it seems like a waste of space, plus the doors would be massive.

If anyone can provide some clarity on this I'd be eternally grateful. Thank you!

[Studio dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHoUG.png)

[Piano dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alTki.png)

Comment: If practical:  Move the piano in before construction is finished, or move the piano in standing on it's side

Comment: An upright piano is only a little over $60$ cm from front to back. It should fit through an ordinary door. Putting a door directly across from the end of an interior wall complicates things, but why would you do that?

Comment: Is there really a wall dividing your studio in the middle? If so please state the distance of this middle wall to your doors. From your drawing apparently 140cm, 70 cm for each of the doors would be enough.

Comment: What you have shown in the picture is inconsistent with what you describe in words. According to the description, it sounds like you have a room with a door to the outside, and in that room a door to another room where the piano is to be placed. If that is the case, all you need is an outer door big enough to get the piano into the first room, and an interior door big enough to get the piano from one room to the other.

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ is the point where your doors will join and $D$ is the point where your middle wall ends, and 80 cm wide door will be enough to move your piano diagonally, with a margin of safety of at about 1 inch on each side, because the distance from point $A$ to point $C$ will be larger than the 65 cm, since the piano is being moved diagonally.

In my picture I suposed your wall ends about 30 cm from where your doors meet. Hope it helps you.

[image]

You can also try [moving the piano](https://www.geogebra.org/m/das4rxdx) in my geogebra simulation. I've made so you can also make the doors narrower, remove the middle wall, or rotate the piano by moving the points C, B and D, until you get another pair of 90 degree angles.[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. This kind of working is exactly what I was looking for. Can I just clarify though, there's a door at the front (Entrance) and the recording room is via another door directly to the left of the entrance. So it needs to be able to get through the entrance and then through the door on the left. I'm not able to see that in your image, unless I'm mistaken? The easy solution would be to make the entrance as wide as the piano, then move it forwards into the entrance and left to the studio. But it seems like an inefficient use of space. Is diagonal possible/better as a solution?

Comment: I've edited my answer, so now you can try moving the piano in my geogebra simulation. I hope it clarifies my answer.